# Cómo hacer esta forma geométrica con css?

Tags: html, css

Quiero hacer esta forma geométrica de la forma más sencilla en propiedades css, sin necesidad de hacer 3 triángulos y un rectángulo. Con el fondo amarillo y el borde rojo como en la imagen...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué código a intentado? El "quiero"  no es tan relevante. "Hice"  es mejor.

Comment: ¿Es SVG una opción?

Comment: No @AlvaroMontoro el problema es que necesito hacerlo lo más simple posible para después poder variar las propiedades de color de borde y fondo sin que la página "pete" ya que habrá mas de un objeto como el de la imagen.

Comment: Con SVG tampoco sería tan complicado, de hecho, creo que sería tan simple como con CSS (o más), y podrías cambiar las propiedades tan fácilmente como con CSS (de hecho, podrías cambiarlas con CSS)

Comment: Ya @AlvaroMontoro lo pensé tras escribir la respuesta, además el tema de la compatibilidad seguro que está mejor resuelto. Si no tienes tiempo para hacer el ejemplo me encantaría que citases alguna fuente donde poder aprender más !

Comment: Te lo pondré  como alternativa en otra respuesta. Y con funcionalidad para que veas que si pones el SVG _inline_ entonces se puede modificar como cualquier otro elemento HTML

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes usar los pseudo-elementos `::before` y `::after` y combinarlos con las transformaciones CSS (en concreto con [`skewY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skewy)) para obtener el efecto que quieres:

```css
.flecha {
  margin:20px;
}

.flecha::before {
  content:"";
  border:2px solid red;
  border-right:0;
  background:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
  -ms-transform: skewY(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-20deg); /* Safari */
  transform: skewY(-20deg);
}

.flecha::after {
  content:"";
  border:2px solid red;
  border-left:0;
  background:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
  -ms-transform: skewY(20deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewY(20deg); /* Safari */
  transform: skewY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flecha"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Como te ponía en un comentario, sería casi más simple hacerlo con SVG, y tendría la ventaja de que sería fácil de escalar y podrías manipularlo igualmente. Aquí te dejo el código que es muy muy sencillo:

```css
svg.flecha {
  overflow:visible;
  fill:yellow;
  stroke:red;
  stroke-width:2px;
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 40" class="flecha">
  <path d="M0,20 50,0 100,20 100,40 50,20 0,40 Z" />
</svg>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo interactivo para que veas que se puede manipular fácilmente usando CSS y un poquito de JavaScript:

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for (var x = 0; x < radios.length; x++) {
  radios[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector("svg").setAttribute("class",  "flecha " + this.value);
  });
}
```

```css
svg.flecha {
  overflow:visible;
  fill:yellow;
  stroke:red;
  stroke-width:2px;
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
}

svg.flecha.verde {
  fill:green;
  stroke:yellow;
}

svg.flecha.azul {
  fill:blue;
  stroke:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="estilo" value="" checked /> Estilo Original
  <input type="radio" name="estilo" value="verde" /> Estilo Verde
  <input type="radio" name="estilo" value="azul" /> Estilo Azul
</div>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 40" class="flecha">
  <path d="M0,20 50,0 100,20 100,40 50,20 0,40 Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Gracias Alvaro!

Comment: Impresionante...